# How can I make a Decodable object from a dictionary?

Tags: swift, decoding

I want to have a Struct that can be instantiated via normal Codable protocol or a Dictionary (Existing code requires the Dictionary instantiation).

I have this code in a playground, but I'm not sure what to do in my 2nd init that takes a Dictionary. How do I make a Decoder object from a dictionary?

```
import Foundation

public protocol Parsable: Decodable {
    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws
}

struct LinkModel: Parsable {
    var href: String
    var text: String

    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {
        href = "/store/options.aspx"
        text = "Buy"
    }
}

struct ResponseModel: Parsable {
    var link: LinkModel?
    let showCell: Bool

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case link
        case showCell = "show"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let linkResponses = try container.decode([LinkModel].self, forKey: .link)
        link = linkResponses.first

        showCell = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .showCell)
    }

    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
        let decoder = ??? // what do I do here?
        self.init(from: decoder)
    }
}


let jsonText = """
{
    "show": true,
    "link": [
        {
        "text": "Buy",
        "href": "/store/options.aspx"
        }
    ]
}
"""

// test standard Decodable instantiation
let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!
let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self, from: jsonData)

print(model.link?.href)

// test dictionary instantiation
...
```

Comment: I'd go with `let decoder = JSONDecoder()` since you are using `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: FWIW This line: `let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self, from: jsonData)` does not ever use/call your `init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {}`. It only calls your `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {}` method. Perhaps what you intended to show/ask about was `let mode = LinkModel(dict:jsonDict)`?

Comment: @Larme That only creates a JSONDecoder. That doesn't conform to type Decoder and doesn't have the container data.

Comment: @Honey That was to test the normal Decode instantiation. Once I figure out the way to use the 2nd init, I'll test it too. Question updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right path.

```
import Foundation

public protocol Parsable: Decodable {
    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws
}

struct LinkModel: Parsable {
    var href: String
    var text: String

    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {
        href = "/store/options.aspx"
        text = "Buy"
    }
}

struct ResponseModel: Parsable {
    var link: LinkModel?
    let showCell: Bool

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case link
        case showCell = "show"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let linkResponses = try container.decode([LinkModel].self, forKey: .link)
        link = linkResponses.first

        showCell = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .showCell)
    }

    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
        // 1.
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        // 2. 
        let result = try decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: jsonData)
        // 3. 
        self = result


    }
}


let jsonText = """
{
    "show": true,
    "link": [
        {
        "text": "Buy",
        "href": "/store/options.aspx"
        }
    ]
}
"""

// test standard Decodable instantiation
let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!
let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self, from: jsonData)

print(model.link?.href)
```

All I did was:

1. create a JSONdecoder object.
2. use that JSONdecoder to decode an object of type `ResponseModel`
3. assign the result of the decoding to `self`. This way all properties of `self` are assigned.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I could assign to self an entire object like that. Cool, that's what I was missing.

Comment: @AaronBratcher FWIW if the object that adopted `Decodable` was a class type, then you would have not been allowed to re-assign `self` in the `init` method. If you tried you'd get the an error: **Cannot assign to value: ‘self’ is immutable**. That is only allowed for structs ie value types.

Answer (score 11):

Extend your `Parsable` protocol to automatically generate the initializer you're looking for.

```
extension Parsable {
    init(dict: [String: Any]) throws {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        self = try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just about to try that.

Comment: I like it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I got an error :  Use of undeclared type 'Parsable'

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr `Parsable` isn't a system protocol. In your case, you could extend `Decodable` and end with the same result.

Comment: This encodes the dictionary into JSON then decodes it again. The solution should be dictionary -> struct instead of dictionary -> json -> struct.